# date.js conflicting with the keith-wood calendar picker

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, jqwidget

[Working example of the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNgPXg90iNQQjvupfLCe?p=preview)

I have a application where I am trying to implement `keith-wood calendar-picker` for differenct calendars and I have also added `date.js` in my application. The problem is date.js and keith-wood together in the same file is not working because of some reason.

Here is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create jqxInput
  $("#input").jqxInput({
    placeHolder: "Enter a Country",
    height: 23,
    width: 350,
    minLength: 1
  });


  if (theme == "black" || theme == "darkblue" || theme == "shinyblack") {
    $("img")[0].src = "../../images/search_white_lg.png"
  }

  $("#input2").calendarsPicker({
    showTrigger: '#search',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic', 'fa'),
    renderer: $.extend({}, $.calendarsPicker.defaultRenderer, {
      picker: $.calendarsPicker.defaultRenderer.picker.
      replace(/\{link:clear\}/, '').
      replace(/\{link:close\}/, ''),
      otherMonthClass: "classforOthersMonths"
    })

  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title id='Description'>This sample illustrates how to add a button after jqxInput. The same approach can be used for adding content before, after, or on both sides of the jqxInput.</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
  <!-- keith wood calendar picker files -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.picker.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.calendars.islamic.js"></script>
  <!--  -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothness.calendars.picker.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,600,700">


</head>

<body class='default'>
  <div id='content'>
    <div id="input">
      <input id="input2" type="text" />
      <div id="search"><img alt="search" width="16" height="16" src="../../images/search_lg.png" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the error message I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: year.calendar is not a function
```

In keith-wood calendar,year is an object type and in date.js year is a integer. Is there any work around to solve this issue?

[Keith-wood calendar picker](http://keith-wood.name/calendarspicker.html)

PS:there is no cdn for keith-wood calendar picker so I can't demonstrate in here. and I can't remove date.js from my application.

Comment: did you found the solution ? I am facing the same issue.